# Some 404 pages are redirecting to other website's pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

In my website some 404 pages are redirecting to other website's pages. When I removed wordpress basic .htaccess code then it goes to 404 page. But as you know we can't remove the basic .htaccess code of wordpress so please tell me the solution how can I get rid of this issue.
Here is the 404 link that is redirecting to another page automatically.
http://www.pro-mixconcrete.co.uk/portfolio/concrete-pump/
And here is the .htaccess code that causing the error.

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

  </IfModule>
```

Comment: Can’t access your example site, it currently only gives me a browser warning about a revoked SSL certificate (after the automatic redirect to the HTTPS version.) This has to be something WP internal though, probably a redirect due to an old post slug having been renamed or something like that.

Comment: You can try this one! https://www.pro-mixconcrete.co.uk/portfolio/concrete-pump/

Comment: @CBroe there is no issue of SSL. Actually the basic code of wordpress .htaccess is creating issue.

Comment: Same thing: “NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED, www.pro-mixconcrete.co.uk normally uses encryption to protect your information. When [browser] tried to connect to www.pro-mixconcrete.co.uk this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. […]
You cannot visit www.pro-mixconcrete.co.uk right now because its certificate has been revoked.”

Comment: _“Actually the basic code of wordpress .htaccess is creating issue.”_ - no, it is not. Rewriting any requests for stuff that does not physically exist, to WordPress’s index.php, is the _job_ of this rewrite code, and it does that as it should here. WordPress itself then decides, whether it has content to serve for the requested URL – or show its own 404 page. Since that does not happen here, something inside WP itself must tell it to redirect this to a new URL instead.

Comment: but I can access the website perfectly right now. There is no issue of revoking anything.

Comment: I am just telling you, what I see in my browser. And https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.pro%2dmixconcrete.co.uk&hideResults=on&latest agrees that there currently appear to be issues, and so does the check under https://www.digicert.com/help/